# Stating the smallest $\sigma$-algebra and a corresponding probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I want to make sure that I understand correctly how to assign probability measures by looking at two examples.

The first random experiment consists of throwing a coin three times. This gives the sample space:  $$\Omega = \{HHH, HHT, HTT, HTH, TTT, TTH, THH, THT\}$$

Now, we are only interested in the event that we have thrown three tails: $$A = \{TTT\}$$

The smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$ is then:

$$\Sigma = \{\emptyset, \Omega, A, A^c \} = \{\emptyset, \Omega, \{TTT\}, \{HHH, HHT, HTT, HTH, TTH, THH, THT\}\}$$

The corresponding probability measure is then:
$$\mathbb{P}(\emptyset) := 0 \\\mathbb{P}(\Omega) := 1 \\\mathbb{P}(\{TTT\}) := \frac{1}{8} \\ \mathbb{P}(\{HHH, HHT, HTT, HTH, TTH, THH, THT\}) := \frac{7}{8}$$

The second random experiment consists of throwing a dice and observing the number of eyes, which gives us: 
$$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

We are only interested in the event that the number of eyes is even:
$$A = \{2,4,6\}$$

The smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$ is then:

$$\Sigma = \{\emptyset, \Omega, A, A^c \} = \{\emptyset, \Omega, \{2,4,6\}, \{1,3,5\}\}$$

The corresponding probability measure is then:
$$\mathbb{P}(\emptyset) := 0 \\\mathbb{P}(\Omega) := 1 \\\mathbb{P}(\{2,4,6\}) := \frac{1}{2}\\ \mathbb{P}(\{1,3,5\}) := \frac{1}{2}$$

Is this correct how one states a corresponding probability measure for the smallest $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.